# Run a shell script as another user that has no password

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I would like to run a script from the main ubuntu shell as a different user that has no password.

I have full sudo privileges, so I tried this:

```
sudo su -c "Your command right here" -s /bin/sh otheruser
```

Then I have to enter my password, but I am not sure if that script is now really running under that user.

How can I confirm that the script is really running under that user now?

Answer (score 543, accepted):

You can do that with `su` or `sudo`, no need for both.

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c 'echo "I am $USER, with uid $UID"'
```

The relevant parts of `man sudo`:

```
-H   The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set
     the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the
     target user (root by default) as specified by the password
     database.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default
     behavior.
```

(Starting from Ubuntu 19.10, `-H` is no longer needed as this is now the default behaviour. See: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1186999/158442))

```
-u user     The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified
      command as a user other than root.  To specify a uid
      instead of a user name, use #uid.  When running commands as
      a uid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped with a
      backslash ('\').  Security policies may restrict uids to
      those listed in the password database.  The sudoers policy
      allows uids that are not in the password database as long
      as the targetpw option is not set.  Other security policies
      may not support this.
```

<del>`su` can only switch user without providing a password if you are root. See Caleb's answer</del>

You can modify the `/etc/pam.d/su` file to allow `su` without password. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password/115090#115090).

If you modified your auth file to the following, any user that was part of group `somegroup` could `su` to `otheruser` without a password.

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = otheruser
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup somegroup
```

Then test from terminal

```
rubo77@local$ su otheruser -c 'echo "hello from $USER"'
hello from otheruser
```

Comment: Can you please add how to do it with just `su` too?

Comment: This asks me for a password :-(

Comment: @IanVaughan, With default configuration (of sudo), you will get asked for a password unless you run it as root. You can configure sudo to "allow user A to run cmd C as user B without requiring a password". See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: I'm prompted for a password when running this as root. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Nate, have you made some changes to the sudoers file. The default configuration allows root to run anything as anyone, without requiring a password.

Comment: WIll this change the `HOME` variable just for the command I run? (meaning that the next ones will be run as before)

Comment: Does this work for GUI applications?

Comment: @Victor Yes, you can try `sudo -H -u user bash -c 'echo ~'`

Comment: This trigger password prompt for me too - even when I already config it not to with `myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` in **sudo visudo**

Comment: @NamGVU keep in mind that order matters. If your sudoers has a rule further down that sets other permissions for your user, or a group you're a member of, that will override your NOPASSWD rule.

Comment: @geirha Thank u for the warning. My `visudo` content is very short and only a few line definin the NOPASSWD as above.

Comment: @geirha sudo -H not working on centos

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan how do you tell it isn't working?

Answer (score 169):

If you want to use su instead of sudo, I believe you can use something like this:

```
su - <username> -c "<commands>"
```

- `-`  will simulate a login of the specified user
- `-c`  tells it that you want to run a command

ps. Unfortunately I'm not able to install ruby using rvm with this method, but that's probably not related.

Comment: I needed to add `sudo` to the beginning otherwise it asked me for my password.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work without `sudo`. with sudo it works, for example: `sudo su - www-data -c "touch /tmp/test"`successfully  created a file as www-data

Comment: To use "su" you need the root password, the point of "sudo" is to avoid that. If you have the root password using "su" as above should work fine.

Comment: _"unfortunately I'm not able to install ruby using rvm with this method"_: when I used this command, the resulting path was bare (e.g., `/bin:/usr/bin`), so my command (similar to your `rvm`) wasn't found.

Comment: and what about switching to a specific group?

Comment: No simulation involved. Using `su`, you are _performing_ a login. `su` literally stands for "switch user". `sudo` lets you mask yourself as the root user, whereas `su` lets you log in as that user (or any user so long as you have the appropriate passwod.) Using `sudo su` is like saying "Hey, this is the root account . Could you switch me to the root account?" That said, it still has it's place.

Answer (score 12):

The answers above are really useful to me but
to answer the actual question...

> How can I affirm that the script is really running under that user now?-

Use:

```
ps -ef | grep <command-name>
```

The output should include your script and the actual user executing it.
People on BSD-like systems, e.g. MAC can find similar information with:

```
ps aux | grep <command-name>
```

Comment: Linux users can use ps aux.

Comment: @DeanHowell; True, but MAC users can not use "ps -ef" and the "ps aux" is BSD options, only available as a compatibility feature while the "ps -ef" is standardized Unix/POSIX options.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you switch to root user with command `sudo su` and then use the command

```
su user -s <command>
```

For example: `su www-data -s bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: For me, it was easier: `sudo su - <user>` as in `sudo su - <user> -s <command>`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Just type in the command `screen -dmS testscreen` this will create a detached screen on your non-sudo user account and then you can log it and check if this screen is there by `screen -ls`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo -u <user> <command>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
root@localhost:/# su - johndoh -c "whoami"
johndoh
root@localhost:/# su - johndoh -c "echo \"hi $(whoami)\""
hi root
root@localhost:/# su - johndoh -c "echo \"hi \$(whoami)\""
hi johndoh
root@localhost:/#
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo` to do this. First, you need to modify the `/etc/sudoers` file to add a rule that allows the `hudson` user to become the other user for the script in question. Let's assume you have a `user1` account that needs to run `/usr/local/bin/my_script.sh`.

Run `visudo` to modify the `sudoers` file.
Then, use the following `sudo` command to run the script from hudson.

It's very important that you use `visudo` to modify the `sudoers` file in order to check the file for errors before putting it in place. Also, I'd suggest a quick read through `man sudoers` in order to clearly understand what the above does before adding it to your configuration.

Comment: You should show the actual line(s) that would be inserted into `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 1):

I have created few users without password using

```
sudo adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --no-create-home user1
sudo adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --no-create-home user2
```

To confirm please check

```
% sudo cat /etc/shadow | grep user
user1:*:19022:0:99999:7:::
user2:*:19022:0:99999:7:::
```

I have written a shell script named `testing.sh` like:

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami
id
```

Now I am going to run this script as different users who do not have any password.

```
$ sudo runuser -u user1 -- bash testing.sh
user1
uid=1001(user1) gid=1001(user1) groups=1001(user1)
$ sudo runuser -u user2 -- bash testing.sh
user2
uid=1002(user2) gid=1002(user2) groups=1002(user2)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate runuser and the double hyphen --?

Answer (score 0):

I use "ssh" pointing to the same local machine.
This enables me to run the shell script or command passwordless.

```
ssh target-user@localhost script-to-execute
```

First, I make sure the host-user saved his public key to the target user (in the same machine).
Then I execute the ssh command I showed above.

The result, is a command/script run as the target user, without even entering a password.