# Autostart software on VServer with user

Tags: server, root, teamspeak

TeamSpeak may not have root privileges. That's why I have a user created with

```
adduser teamspeak
```

I want to start TeamSpeak with the `teamspeak` user.

How I can add an "autostart" for my VServer (Ubuntu14.04) that is started by this user? Because, when I reboot the server, then it should also restart TeamSpeak.

Answer (score 2):

You can start any process as another user with `su` or `sudo`, no need for both.

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c 'echo "I am $USER, with uid $UID"'
```

So, to start TeamSpeak as the `teamspeak` user, use

```
sudo -H -u teamspeak <path_to_TeamSPeak>/TeamSpeak
```

See [Run a shell script as another user that has no password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password) for more details.

To "autorun" this at start up, there are many ways to do this. You could use an rc script:

- Place the line above into a text file called `autostart_teamspeak.sh`, and save it in `/usr/local/bin`, for example. You could run `chmod +x autostart_teamspeak.sh` as well, to make it executable.
- Edit `/etc/rc.local` to add the line `sh +x /usr/local/bin/autostart_teamspeak.sh` which will call the script, upon start up.

For other ways for achieving the same, see [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up).