# How to run IntelliJ IDEA as a dedicated system user?

Tags: permissions, sudo, security, gksu, intellij

## the problem

I installed **IntelliJ IDEA** on my system (to `/opt/jetbrains`), and want it to be able to modify its files (do self-updating) without enabling any other process to modify them.

---

## the configuration

I've come up that I will need a system user, to whom the `/opt/jetbrains` directory will belong to, and I will run IDEA as that user:

```
# Set up things
sudo mkdir /opt/jetbrains
sudo adduser --system --home /opt/jetbrains jetbrains
sudo chown jetbrains /opt/jetbrains

# Install IDEA
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2017.1.2.tar.gz -O idea.tar.gz
sudo -u jetbrains tar -xzf idea.tar.gz -C /opt/jetbrains/
rm idea.tar.gz

# Configure idea.desktop
# set the 'Exec' line, to run as user jetbrains
```

---

## what i tried

I have read [Run a shell script as another user that has no password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password#294748)

I tried the following, but I got an error, as well as a password prompt.

- `sudo su -c "/opt/jetbrains/idea-ultimate/bin/idea.sh" -s /bin/sh jetbrains`
- `sudo -u jetbrains /opt/jetbrains/idea-ultimate/bin/idea.sh`

Both output:

```
No protocol specified

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
  at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
  at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
  at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
  at ...
```

I also tried `gksu -w -u jetbrains gksu /opt/jetbrains/idea-ultimate/bin/idea.sh`, but that prompted me a password  - of user `jetbrains`, who obviously has no password.

Comment: Probably you want to install the IDE into the home of that new user, instead of `/opt`. However, running it with that user will give you problems when you try to modify projects into *your* home directory.

Answer (score 4):

It's late, but hopefully it helps someone. I'm doing this:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:foxx1337 && sudo -u foxx1337 /opt/jetbrains/idea-ultimate/bin/idea.sh
```

This is based on the wonderful reply sim gave here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108784/running-gui-application-as-another-non-root-user

Comment: As an extra, do not forget to allow your user to sudo with no password prompt to the target user (otherwise the command can't be used in an X session).