# Scripting the hiding of username on login screen (18.04)

Tags: bash, scripts, 18.04, login-screen, gdm

I have a script to set up an ubuntu workstation with standard settings.  One of the things it did on 16.04 was hide the usernames from the login screen.

Moving to 18.04 and I am having some difficulty managing to do this.   From what I can see to do

```
gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
```

If I run this in a script as `sudo tweaks.sh` it gives errors, the only way I can manage to get it to work is manually by doing a change to `gdm` user

```
su gdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
exit
```

I have tried the following ways to make it less interactive but all fail

```
sudo -u gdm -H sh -c "gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true"
```

or

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
```

Any suggest how I can make this change from a script?

Comment: According to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/294748/214944, you should try: `sudo -H -u gdm bash -c 'gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true'`

Comment: @ponsfrilusl   that errors with `Error spwaning command line "dbus-launch --autolaunch=d3b8183928cd438fa0149f458ae87f66 --binary-syntax --close-stderr": Child process exited;`

Comment: ok I think I have it working now  `sudo -u gdm base -c  'dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true'`  it does give an error of `No protocol specified` but gives the desired result.

Comment: Are you sure about the `base` command ?

Comment: woops typo  should have read `bash`

Answer (score 1):

My solution thanks to help from @ponsfrilusl

```
sudo -u gdm bash -c 'dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true' > /dev/null 2&>1
```

It outputs `No protocol specified` this can be ignored by appending `> /dev/null 2&>1` to mute this.