# Postgres dropdb and createdb commands in sudoers as a different user

Tags: command-line, sudo, postgresql

I regularly need to drop a postres database and recreate it. It has to be done as `postgres` user as following:

```
$ sudo -u postres dropdb my_database
```

I thought of adding **sudoers rules** for not being asked a password. Usually I proceed by creating a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` with a rule like this one:

```
Cmnd_Alias DROP_DB = /bin/bash -l -c dropdb*, /usr/bin/dropdb*
emilio ALL = NOPASSWD: DROP_DB
```

But in this use case, I need to run the command as **postgres** user and it doesn't work.

What is the proper way to run a command as a different user without being asked a password?

EDIT: This might be a duplicate but it brings a different solution using `visudo` which is interesting.

Comment: Try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password

Comment: It clearly is a duplicate but I let it here for the solution it brings using ```visudo```.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap **dropdb** and **createdb** in a bash script like `/usr/bin/recreatedb.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u postgres dropdb $2
sudo -u postgres createdb -O $1 $2
```

Then create a special **sudoers** rule using **visudo**:

```bsh
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/postgresql
```

With this rule:

```bsh
Cmnd_Alias RECREATE_DB = /bin/bash -l -c recreatedb*, /usr/bin/recreatedb*
username ALL = NOPASSWD: RECREATE_DB
```